# Retrieve rows on the basis of repeating value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I want to retrieve data from my table `Card`.

```
table Card(
  MembershipNumber,
  EmbossLine,
  status,
  EmbossName
)
```

Such that only those rows should be returned that have repeating MembershipNumber i.e having `count` greater than 1.
Like if I Have following records

```
(11,0321,'active','John')
(11,0322,'active','John')
(23,0350,'active','Mary')
(46,0383,'active','Fudge')
(46,0382,'active','Fudge')
(46,0381,'active','Fudge')
```

The query should return all records except the third one. Is it possible?

**EDITED** I got the answer for my question. I have another query. I want to filter the rows by `status` too but when I run the following query I dont get the desired result:

```
SELECT EmbossLine,Membershipnumber,status,embossname,*
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   card) A
WHERE cnt > 1 AND status='E0'
```

Before Adding `status` in the where clause, it works perfectly fine. see Picture[image]

After adding filtering by status

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Count() Over()` window function to do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   youurtable) A
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

**Demo**

```
SELECT MembershipNumber,
       [status],
       EmbossName
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   (VALUES (11.0321,'active','John'),
                       (11.0322,'active','John'),
                       (23.0350,'active','Mary'),
                       (46.0383,'active','Fudge'),
                       (46.0382,'active','Fudge'),
                       (46.0381,'active','Fudge')) tc (MembershipNumber, [status], EmbossName)) A
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Comment: Sir one more thing; I want to filter the records further by `status`. I tried the following but didn't get the desired result `SELECT EmbossLine,Membershipnumber,status,embossname,*
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   card) A
WHERE  cnt > 1 AND status='inactive'`
Where should I add `status='inactive'` to make it appropriate?

Comment: @Nuke - Your `status` column doesnt have `E0` value.

Comment: @Nuke - Syntax wise it is correct. Do you have any duplicate rows with inactive status

Comment: When Im adding status to filter I am getting distinct records too, Those that have no duplicate membershipnumber

Comment: @Nuke - can you add some sample data

Comment: its returning all those rows that are `inactive` but having `Membershipnumber` count < 0

Comment: @Nuke - I can help you more if i see an example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CARD a WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CARD b WHERE b.MembershipNumber = a.MembershipNumber) > 1
```

should do it

Comment: No its returning distinct rows

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.* from card c
join (select MembershipNumber from table group by
        MembershipNumber having count(MembershipNumber) > 1) mem
on mem.MembershipNumber = c.MembershipNumber
```

Or

```
Select * from table where MembershipNumber in
(select MembershipNumber from table group by
        MembershipNumber having count(MembershipNumber) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the duplicates on empbossname  and get the result

```
select t1.* from card as t1 inner join 
(select empbossname from card group by empbossname  having count(*)>1) as t2
on t1.empbossname =t2.empbossname
```

Comment: I have a large data and two persons may have same EmbossName